# React-redux connect passes props too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am writing simple audio player using react-native. And i have got an issue about passing props to component across react-redux connect method.

Here is my Container code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Music from './Music';
import MusicActions from '../../Actions/MusicActions';

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  tracksObject: store.MusicReducer.get('tracks'),
  isLoaded: store.MusicReducer.get('isLoaded'),
  isLoading: store.MusicReducer.get('isLoading'),
  playing: store.MusicReducer.get('playing'),
  duration: store.MusicReducer.get('duration'),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  movePan: value => dispatch(MusicActions.movePan(value)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Music);
```

And here is few methods from component

```
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if (this.props.playing) {
      const step = this.props.duration * 0.025;
      const stepFrequency = this.props.duration / step;
      const intervalID = setInterval(
        () => this.setState(state => ({ sliderValue: 
(state.sliderValue + step) })),
    stepFrequency,
      );

      this.setState({ intervalID });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <View>
          { this.renderSongList() }
       </View>
       <Slider
          value={this.state.sliderValue}
          onValueChange={(value) => { this.onSliderChange(value); }}
          style={styles.slider}
          minimumTrackTintColor="#ba383a"
          thumbStyle={{ top: 22, backgroundColor: '#ba383a' }}
       />
      </View>
   ); 
 }
```

When song loads and stores value 'playing' becomes true, components method componentWillReceiveProps calls, but this.props.playing flag is false in spite of it is true in mapStateToProps.
But after componentWillReceiveProps render calls and this.props.playing is true there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is expected behavior, in `componentWillReceiveProps`, `this.props` is a reference to the previous props. You'll want to use the `nextProps` parameter of `componentWillRecieveProps`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.playing) {
    // Rest of code
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a common mistake. Don't forget to accept the solution that works for you.